# jquery autocomplete (NOT UI) , match beginning of the words

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I dont use UI and I dont plan to include a 222 kb file just for this purpose...So is there any way to modify autocomplete file, so that we could match beginning of the words?

I found this part:

```
           lookupFilter: function (suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
                return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) !== -1;
            },
```

Changing it to

```
=== 0
```

will search for beginning of a phrase, but how to search for beginning of each word? I know its a Regexp function, but anyhow I tried it wont work.

p.s: Im using this plugin http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

thanks

Comment: "I dont plan to include a 222 kb file just for this purpose" - you don't need to, do you? You can generate a custom download of UI with just autocomplete.

Comment: you must fetch data from server. is it your meaning?

Comment: Rup, is it same as this one http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ ? I modified it a bit, looked at ui code, its completely different. By the way, is it 2 different scripts? Or UI is a modified version of it?

Comment: alright, I figured it myself. It doesnt let me to answer, so thanks all for attention.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Typeahead? It has several options for matching and can potentially solve your problem.

http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/